# Cryengine 3 Cgf Upload Failed

Tags: import, game-development, 3dsmax, cryengine

I see this error when I stage an object that I imported from 3ds max. The error I get is:

```
[Warning] CGF Upload failed : Directory stream 8 cannot be from 32-bit to 16-bit format because it contains directory 65535 [File=demo/3D/Sofa.cgf].
```

What resource method can I use to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you transfer the object by separating it into certain groups, the problem disappears.  I'm open to other suggestions.